# 'Stuff' And 'FOR XML PATH' alternative in Mysql for the following stored prodedure of Ms-sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, dbmigrate

I have the following query in Ms-Sql

```
  INSERT INTO tbl_web_price_update 

    Select bd_book_code,

    Case 
        When pd.bpd_price is null then  
            cast((a.bd_price*c.ptm_price) as numeric(10))   
        else
            cast((pd.bpd_price*c.ptm_price) as numeric(10))             
        end
    As Price

    from tbl_books_details a 
        inner join tbl_price_type_master c on a.bd_price_type = c.ptm_price_type_id 
        left join tbl_books_price_details pd on pd.bpd_book_code = a.bd_book_code 
    Where c.ptm_price_type_id = @price_type     

    SELECT distinct r.price, STUFF((SELECT distinct ','+ Cast(a.bd_book_code as varchar) FROM tbl_web_price_update a WHERE r.price = a.price FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '') FROM tbl_web_price_update r
```

I have migrated from ms-sql to my-sql and i am unable to write an alternative query in Mysql. Please Help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for something like this

```
SELECT price, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bd_book_code) bd_book_code
  FROM tbl_web_price_update
 GROUP BY price
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b95f/1)** demo

- [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cd.diNumber ORDER BY cd.diNumber ASC SEPARATOR ',') FROM transactionalPlms.vw_consignmentDetails cd WHERE cd.tripid = t.tripid) as di_numberaa,   
    (SELECT (cd.diNumber)  FROM transactionalPlms.vw_consignmentDetails cd 
                      where cd.tripid = t.tripid) as di_number,
    (SELECT (cd.MaterialCode)  FROM transactionalPlms.vw_consignmentDetails cd 
                      where cd.tripid = t.tripid) as MaterialCode,
    (SELECT (cd.noofbags)  FROM transactionalPlms.vw_consignmentDetails cd 
                      where cd.tripid = t.tripid) as NoofBags, sd.plannedPacker
FROM transactionalPlms.trip t
Inner join transactionalPlms.sequencingDetail sd on t.tripid = sd.tripId and sd.status = 'A'
Inner join masterPLms.vehicleMaster vm on t.vehicleNumber = vm.registration_number and vm.status = 'A'
where t.status = 'A'
order by sd.manualSequence desc, t.yardIn desc;
```